# datagridview fill/load data using progressbar

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hope someone can help me! How can I apply a progressbar to a datagridview.
I have a button, when I click it, the records in database loads in a datagridview, but I have many records so when the data is loading, the application looks like it's frozen, I need that the user see the progressbar so he knows its loading.

This is my code for the load:

```
                Dim conex As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DATABSE;Integrated Security=True")
                    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1", conex)
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    dv.Table = ds.Tables(0)
                    DataGridV1.DataSource = dv
```

I've searched and view many answers but I still don't get it using backgroundworker. Or where can I get a good information about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **maybe** instead of a progressbar, you could refine the query so it is not returning every single row and every single column?  If there is so much data you need something to entertain the user, they cant possibly be able to consume that much data.  Consider pulling back the 100 most recently updated rows, or reuse the filter they last used.

Comment: Its freezing up because of the call to get the Data and fill the datagridview which in turns freezes the UI. I would recommend using a backgroundworker to do the heavy lifting and your UI wouldn't lock up. Just a suggestion...

Comment: On another note I believe there's a marquee progress bar style that animates for you, when your data is loading show it and when done hide it...

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answers! I think I'll go for the most recent updated rows (@Plutonix) using the marquee style (@Mr CoDeXeR) This answers have been much help, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that is not exactly what you ask but you can use a `AllowPaging="True"` with `PageSize="60"`  in gridview this will speed up the results or you can use a "fake" progress bar (animation image)  with message "Plese wait..." which will be hidden after the page loads.

Comment: @ ooopsoft, I'll go on with a marquee progressbar style, I just want to let know the user that records al loading. Thanks a lot!